# C# Mongodb. Compare dates by Date property or Year, Month, Day

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have the following object:

```
public class DayHours
{
   public WorkType WorkType {get; set;}
   public IList<Hours> Hours {get; set;}
}

public class Hours 
{
   public DateTime Begin {get; set;}
   public DateTime End {get; set;}
   public TimeStatus Status {get; set;}
}
```

I want to query `Hours` by specific day, month and year:

```
_collection.AsQueryable()
   .Where(d => d.WorkType == workType)
   .SelectMany(d => d.Hours)
   .Where(h => someDate.Date == h.Begin.Date);
```

But, I get exception

> {{Begin.Date}}.Date is not supported

I tried to compare by year, month and day explicitly:

```
.Where(h => someDate.Year == h.Begin.Year && ...);
```

Anyway, I get exception that `Year` is not supported.
How to query by part of the date properly?

Comment: What type of query you are building? Perhaps you could create a criteria for your filter e.g. >= 9/10/2017 5pm && <= 9/10/2017 7pm

Comment: Code works fine for me! Is the error reported at compile time or run time? If at run time, what is the type of exception? Is it NullReferenceException on Begin? And I hope `DateTime` here refers to `System.DateTime` and not your own defined class!

Comment: What's `someDate` belongs to? You can use `someDate` as border so that just comparing two `DateTime`, not its properties (the DB provider may not support `Date` property in LINQ yet).

Comment: @ShishirGupta yes, at run time. The exception type is `InvalidOperationException`. `DateTime` is .NET type, not my own.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto the `someDate` is just `DateTime.Now`.

Comment: What happens if you changed to compare two `DateTime` directly: `.SingleOrDefault(h => h.Begin == someDate)`? I think `someDate.Date` still resulting `DateTime` property too, without time component.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Need to check, but, I am almost sure that time will be compared too. Because I have code that checks if some datetime in range and it works fine.

Comment: I think you can strip out time component for `DateTime.Now` outside the LINQ query first: `someDate = DateTime.Now.Date`, then use `someDate` in LINQ without using `Date` property anymore.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto, yes, but, In the databse values with time. For exampe, `Begin: 2017-11-09T03:30:00.000Z` and `End: 2017-11-09T017:30:00.000Z`. And I want to find all `Hours` with specific date, without comparing time. In the question I use `SingleOrDefault`, but it's not important, I changed it to `Where`

Comment: I see that you're using `Begin` & `End` property to mark a date range, why don't using something like `.SingleOrDefault(h => h.Begin >= someDate && h.End <= otherDate)` (`someDate` & `otherDate` using `DateTime.Now.Date` & `DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(1)` outside query)? What exactly you want to achieve using `Hours` class?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto yes, it's the one option. But, the question is about Date, Day, Year, Month properties. If it's not possible to use it then I will choose another way and will create  feature request for the C# driver. I have not found any related issues so decided to ask community first.

Comment: @user348173: Can you post the complete stack trace?